# Online debugger and transaction analyzer for Solana

Tags: development, debug

does anyone know an online debugger and transaction analyzer for Solana, like Tenderly on Ethereum? Or others tools like transactions visualizers with detailed list of executed instructions, visualization of token flows..
I come from Eth dev and I don't find alternatives of the tools I use in the Eth ecosystem.
Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that people familiar enough with Solana to answer your question are not familiar with Tenderly. Update your question to explain what Tenderly is, what it does, and then maybe someone will be able to point you in the right direction.